# Detect key press in Python without running as root and without BlockingIOError

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, io

I'm trying to detect key presses to use for a terminal game. I don't want to have to run the file as root. I've been using this code and it seems to work ok...

```py
import termios, fcntl, sys, os
from gemini import Scene

scene = Scene((40, 15))

def wait_for_key_press(self):
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()

    oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)

    oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

    try:
        while True:
            try:
                c = sys.stdin.read(1)
                if c:
                    return c
            except IOError: pass
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

except when i use it in a thread like this:

```py
def move_square():
    while True:
        square.move(1,0)
        sleep(.1)
        scene.render()

def player_ctrl():
    while True:
        input = wait_for_key_press()
        match input:
            pass # move player based on the pressed key

threading.Thread(target=player_ctrl).start()
move_square()
```

at which point it returns the following error:

```
  File "/Users/redpenguin/Documents/Code/Python/Gemini Engine/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    move_square()
  File "/Users/redpenguin/Documents/Code/Python/Gemini Engine/main.py", line 14, in move_square
    scene.render()
  File "/Users/redpenguin/Documents/Code/Python/Gemini Engine/gemini.py", line 200, in render
    print(seperator+"\n".join(["".join(row) for row in display])+"\n")
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] write could not complete without blocking
```

What does BlockingIOError mean, and is there a better way to get text input in the terminal?